# How to upgrade Sceneform's source code to androidx?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, arcore, sceneform

I am using androidStudio-4.1 version and there the sceneform plugin is deprecated. So I included a module from GitHub https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk and use the same steps as suggested on Github but getting an error at ***"import android.support.annotation.Nullable;"*** and another related import issue.

I understood that I need to upgrade Sceneform's source code to `androidx` but I do not know how to do this.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork of Sceneform which is currently being kept up to date and which already has this update to AndroidX included and tested:

- https://github.com/thomasgorisse/sceneform-android-sdk

It might be useful to consider using this as you may get better support and a wider community of people to share information with if you do.

See also the thread which refers to this fork and some recent experience using Sceneform after the official depreciation of the origin library: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/1049

Answer (score 0):

replace line ***"import android.support.annotation.Nullable;"*** with ***"import androidx.annotation.Nullable;"*** through-out folder files ('sceneformsrc', 'sceneformux').
Make sure that you only implement one sceneform inside ***build.gradle*** file.

Goto build --> Rebuild Project, the problem will be resolved